# Jenkins unable to start Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: windows, jenkins, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a batch file I have made that runs Oracle's VirtualBox in the headless mode. When I run the command in the windows command prompt it works fine without any errors.

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage startvm "Ubuntu" --type headless
Waiting for VM "Ubuntu" to power on...
VM "Ubuntu" has been successfully started.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>
```

However, when I call the batch script that has the same command via Jenkins I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage startvm "Ubuntu" --type headless 
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: The object is not ready
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component VirtualBoxClientWrap, interface IVirtualBoxClient
```

Every VirtualBox command called from Jenkins gives the same error.

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage sharedfolder add "Ubuntu" --name BranchRepo --hostpath "A PATH" --automount 
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: The object is not ready
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component VirtualBoxClientWrap, interface IVirtualBoxClien
```

Any suggestions as to how to fix this issue? Is there some particular way to grant Jenkins the required permissions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that that the user with which it runs has incorrect permissions.
You can try and run Jenkins' service as a separate local admin user.
Start => 'services' => Scroll to the Jenkins service => right click => properties => "log on" => "this account" => specify a local admin account.
**Edit**:
Editing the "Registry Editor" worked

Comment: Hi, I have only one account on this system and I have set the "log on" as this user but am still facing this issue. Since this is a work laptop the user does not have "admin rights" unless I explicitly raise it every 24hrs. I can start Ubuntu on this user via command line without raising admin rights. Do I still have to raise admin rights to start Ubuntu via Jenkins?

Comment: @AdishRao yes you can try that option and if it doesnt then it would be needed

Comment: It still did not work after raising admin rights. Would like to inform you that after a lot of googling and messing around I found that editing the "Registry Editor" finally worked for me. Thanks for the help! (And sorry for the very late reply!)

Comment: @AdishRao Cool. I would edit the answer , so that people can learn